# After publishing a component the category which is used in that component gets unpublished

Tags: publishing

We are publishing a component which successfully gets published but the category that it is referring gets unpublished or its entry gets removed from ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS in the Broker database. Please can anyone help us?

Comment: Are you sure the component is still linked to that keyword? It should get removed only if you changed it in the CM too

Comment: Isn't it the TAXFACETs table that stores the published category?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but some items you could look into :

1. When publishing do you see the keyword in the 'items to publish' dialog?
2. Has the keyword/ category been modified to disable publishing?
3. Has your storage_conf.xml been changed in a way that you're doing 'something else' with the keywords?  Perhaps it was published before and since there's been some changes?